# Allow reports checked still Custom object not visible

Tags: reporting, custom-object, dashboard

I have Allow Reports checked at object level. Still while creating report the object is not visible. Can someone please let me know why?

Comment: Object permission on profile??
Also, have you checked it as deployed?

Comment: yes it is there. I can see records created

Comment: did you hide some report types on the `Create New Report` page ?

Comment: No, I didnt. Dont know why not working